# Cannot use this in Builder Android Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, this

I am trying to use a Bulider from a library that i have imported in my project but for some reason the Builder doesn't accept 'this' as Service context. if anyone can help me out i would truly appreciate it. Thanks

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.SubActionButton;
import com.example.andrew.reddit2go.R;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
* Created by Justeen on 2015-02-26.
*/
public class FloatService extends Service {

private WindowManager windowManager;
public TextView textView;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private FloatingActionButton rightLowerButton;
private FloatingActionButton topCenterButton;

private FloatingActionMenu rightLowerMenu;
private FloatingActionMenu topCenterMenu;

private boolean serviceWillBeDismissed;
//keep track of an instance to communicate with
private static FloatService floatingInstance;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    FloatService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return FloatService.this;
    }
}

public FloatService(){

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    serviceWillBeDismissed = false;
    floatingInstance = FloatService.this;

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    textView.setText("0");

    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable shape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_box);
    //textView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setBackground(shape);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(textView, params);

    try {
        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;
            private final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
            private long startClickTime;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                        //if this is not a move, consider it a click and start the activity to see the posts
                        if(clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                            Intent activityStart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            activityStart.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(activityStart);
                        }
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(textView, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    rightLowerButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(textView)
            .setSystemOverlay(true)
            .setLayoutParams(params)
            .build();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand( Intent intent , int flags , int startId ) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (textView != null) windowManager.removeView(textView);
    floatingInstance = null;
}

//called to update the number on this ChatHead
public void updateUnreadNum(int unreadPosts){
    if (null != textView) {
        Log.d("Reddit2Go", "number of posts is: " + unreadPosts);
        textView.setText(""+unreadPosts);
    }
}

//called to update the list of available networks and the number on this ChatHead
public void updateUnreadNum(int unreadPosts, String networkList){
    if (null != textView) {
        Log.d("Reddit2Go", "number of posts is: " + unreadPosts);
        //textView.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(""+unreadPosts+" Cached\n" + networkList);
    }
}

//get a reference to a running instance of this service
public static FloatService getFloatingInstance(){
    return floatingInstance;
}
}
```

[image: this is the error i am getting]

Comment: You may be using an old version of the library. In [this commit from Dec. 24](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu/commit/3641a8819d3dc756ca4f1e02f1eb34dee9acbb7d#diff-c7d6d5edaf9d8dafefeceb59b9f4fec2R221), the `Builder` constructor parameter was changed from `Activity` to `Context`, allowing any context extension (incl. services) to create an instance.

Comment: i am actually using the same version of the library

Comment: then it should not be the case I think . You should try using YourClassName.this

Comment: or is it possible that maven central hasn't updated the AAR file? as that's the one i am using

Comment: @JustinMacwan: Right, so you mean you're using the `com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2` dependency? Based on a [quick look at Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oguzdev/CircularFloatingActionMenu), it appears that release was from the early days (July 2014) of the library (even though it's the latest). You're going to have to use the latest source in stead, I guess. Or ask the maintainer to publish an update.

Comment: my bad here, i am actually using an old version of the library in fact as as the file i downloaded from maven central isn't updated

Comment: thank you very much, i will just download the library instead and add it to my project